# Jetty is not sending the Content-Length header

Tags: java, http-headers, jetty, embedded-jetty, content-length

I have a servlet in embedded Jetty that provides downloads for certain files.

The code I use is the following:

```java
try{
    File file = new File(filePath);
    response.setContentLengthLong(file.length());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfilename.mkv");
    response.setContentType(Files.probeContentType(file.toPath()));
    response.setBufferSize(5242880);
    in = new FileInputStream(file);
    out = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[5242880];
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        try {
            out.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            logger.debug("Reached end of file, breaking loop");
            break;
        }
    }
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For some reason, when I access this servlet from Chrome, the download starts, but I do not see the download percentage nor the total size of the file, and when I check the response headers of the request, `Content-Length` is not there, but `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` is.
I have tried removing the `Content-Disposition` header, but the result is the same.

I also tried to set a fake content length header instead of `file.length()` and set it to `response.setContentLengthLong(10000);` (the file is several GB). The download stops after those 10k bytes.

Another note, while debugging, the response object does have the content length header, but for some reason it is deleted or overwritten automatically.

What could the problem be?

**Update after adding response.flushBuffer()**:

```
String filePath = "path/to/file";
try {
    // Starting the actual stream. It will handle videos differently from other files, in order to support streaming
    Path file = Paths.get(filePath);
    response.setContentLengthLong(Files.size(file));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileEntity.fileName + fileEntity.extension + "\"");
    response.setContentType(Files.probeContentType(file));
    response.flushBuffer();

    final int bufferSize = response.getBufferSize();
    try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file)) {
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

Here are my jetty dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the problem was not jetty or any part of the code, but it was in the apache virtualhost configuration. After i removed the following lines it started sending the Content-Length header as expected:

```
   SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI  \
        \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI  \
        \.(?:mp3|wav|wma|au|m4p|snd|mid|wmv|mpg|mpeg|mp4|qt|mov)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI  \
        \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|gz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

Answer (score 1):

When you used `response.setBufferSize(5242880);` you reset any header that deals with the output buffer/stream/cache (including `Content-Length`).

Remove that setting, any value over the MTU of your networking interface is pointless waste of resources and does not result in any faster transfer rate than the default (which is 32k).

A value that high is basically resulting in the local JVM buffer being filled, then blocked, while its being written to the network in MTU sized chunks.

Check it yourself, I bet it wont ever be over 65536 (and more than often only 1500)

```java
package net;

import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class WhatIsMyMTU {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException{
        Collection<NetworkInterface> ifaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface iface : ifaces)
            System.out.printf("iface: %s - MTU=%d%n", iface, iface.getMTU());
    }
}
```

Next, if you want to fix your headers in stone, commit the headers before you start sending the response.

Use `response.flushBuffer()` before you call `response.getOutputStream()`

An example of how this HttpServlet would look can be found in the embedded-jetty-serving-huge-files project at

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-serving-huge-files

Look closely at the [`MyFilesServlet`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-serving-huge-files/blob/jetty-10.0.x/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/MyFileServlet.java) to see how it works.

You can also look at the [`ServerTest`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-serving-huge-files/blob/jetty-10.0.x/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/ServerTest.java) to see that it does send `Content-Length` in both use cases (Using `DefaultServlet` and using the [`MyFilesServlet`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-serving-huge-files/blob/jetty-10.0.x/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/MyFileServlet.java))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i di have some questions about it: if i remove `response.setBufferSize(5242880);` how do i then treat the while loop? How many bytes should i read?
Also, i did add `response.flushBuffer()` before `response.getOutputStream()` and removed the line `response.setBufferSize(5242880);` but i still don't get the content-length header.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can leave it at default servlet buffersize (of 32k) and write a single 2GB byte buffer array and it will work. (albeit with a senseless waste of memory)  Jetty will hold that buffer and serve it one buffer at a time to the remote client in a threadless way.  In the servlet spec you don't have raw buffer access to the network layer anyway.

Comment: Got it, but how am i still not getting the content-length after the modifications you suggested?

Comment: Did you use the `response.flushBuffer()` like what was recommended?

Comment: Yes, i will update the answer so you can see

Comment: I updated the example project at https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-serving-huge-files

Comment: Your example uses jetty 10 but my project uses jetty 11, i don't know if that can be a cause for this problem. Other than that, i tried to part of the code that is responsible for downloading the file, and i still get no content length header. See the question's updated section after " **Update after adding response.flushBuffer():** "

Comment: There's a `jetty-11.0.x` branch on that example project.

Comment: The test cases show that `Content-Length` header is most definitely sent on all use cases.   At this point I think you are not analyzing the response headers properly, or have something between your Jetty server and your client that is modifying the response.

Comment: After a lot of testing i found that the problem was apache in this case. It had a DEFLATE  output filter with some SetEnvIfNoCase statements in the virtualhost for the api. After i removed that it works fine.